# MATLAB ismember function with 'rows' option fails on GPU

Tags: matlab

When I run the command:

```
[Lia, Locb] = ismember(gpuArray(Ent_Pair_Pos), gpuArray(Ent_Pair_Dmel), 'rows')
```

I get this error:

> Error using gpuArray/ismember Failed to initialize GPU BLAS library.

The data files can be downloaded from

- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_l51j5wcRSf1gvPxPq-goiIM0nHVCiO7 and
- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T497EmvcsApIUkUWTefFGEvtsPoGnRDE

They can be loaded into MATLAB workspace by running load Ent_Pair_Dmel.txt and load Ent_Pair_Pos.txt.

In addition, here is the output of the `gpuDevice` command.

CUDADevice with properties:

```
                  Name: 'GeForce GTX TITAN X'
                 Index: 1
     ComputeCapability: '5.2'
        SupportsDouble: 1
         DriverVersion: 9
        ToolkitVersion: 7.5000
    MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
      MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
    MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
           MaxGridSize: [2.1475e+09 65535 65535]
             SIMDWidth: 32
           TotalMemory: 1.2795e+10
       AvailableMemory: 1.1801e+10
   MultiprocessorCount: 24
          ClockRateKHz: 1076000
           ComputeMode: 'Default'
  GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
      CanMapHostMemory: 1
       DeviceSupported: 1
        DeviceSelected: 1
```

I am using MATLAB Version: 9.0.0.341360 (R2016a) on Ubuntu 14.04. 
Any idea regarding the error?

Comment: Can you run other functions on the GPU? Try for example a matrix multiplication. I doubt it's specific to `ismember`, and am sure it is not the 'rows' argument. :)

Comment: Have you tried to split the command into several? e.g. running `gpuArray(Ent_Pair_Pos)` and `gpuArray(Ent_Pair_Dmel)` first and save them in temporary variables, then apply `ismember`.

Comment: Its working without 'rows', I have made data available you can try. Only when 'rows' included I see that error.  I value your time

Comment: Ander Biguri thanks for nice edit